# Dynamic Schemas in Rails Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails 4.2, I am aware we can do:

```
self.table_name = 'users'
```

However, I have an app which has *some* models in schemas for the client. It's not true multi-tenancy as not *all* models are in schemas; some are shared. Just private information, for example, on users is in each schema.

I know we can do:

```
self.table_name = 'schema_name.users'
```

However, what if each `schema_name` is different - per client? I can successfully insert data into the one schema's users table, however, in the same session, if I try to insert it into the other, it never gets saved there. I think the table_name is cached and therefore, stays set...

Any suggestions? I am sure this is possible in Rails.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can go is use the gem **Apartment** that does all this and handles shared tables across the different tenants, check it out at https://github.com/influitive/apartment

Other way is to set the schema in the controller, before hitting the database, something like:

```
User.table_name = 'schema_name.users'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What if this was for creation through a model, however? I'll check out Apartment...

Comment: If I have a User model, before a create I'll run this `User.table_name = 'schema_name.users'`

Comment: Oh awesome! So I had a `before_action` in `ApplicationController` which calls `set_runtime_organization` which reads from a cookie the organization. From there, I can do `ModelName.table_name = "#{schema_name}.model_name` as an example. This should work fine I am sure...

Comment: I think this should work  - this is for a handful of models. Perhaps Apartment may be overkill and your method will do it. I'll simply put the `ModelName.table_name` as I posted above. Thank you!

Comment: Make some tests, it should work, one benefit of apartment is the migrations by schema. I'll modify my answer to include that class code, let me know if it worked :)

Comment: neydroid - added some tests, works fine. I have something that switches the user and for the "private" models, used your code ie `ModelName.table_name = "#{schema_name}.model_name"`. Is this dangerous to do - hackish or should it be okay?

Comment: is great that it worked! I'm not sure if is thread safe, that's something to research